# Track user location in Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am building a bot using `Microsoft Bot Framework`, I wanted to track the location of users location who is using the bot. Is this possible ?

I found one library `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Location` which return the Maps when you enter the address.

Comment: You can try with [Microsoft Location control](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Location) for Microsoft BOT Framework!!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/teams-js/location?view=msteams-client-js-latest  & https://stackoverflow.com/a/51431677/9599453

Comment: Does the above helped?

Comment: @Ashish Kumar: Above sample code and document shared by Dev will help you.

Comment: Moving this to answer. Consider upvoting it. So it will be useful to others/community.

Comment: @Rama-MSFT I wanted to track the location of user without the user interaction. Not the address lookup .

Answer (score 0):

- You can try with [Microsoft Location control for Microsoft BOT Framework](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Location).
- I tested it and it works!!